# Why are docker host volumes being mounted incorrectly?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-machine

I'm running docker-machine on an El Capitan Mac. I'm trying to mount a host directory onto a specific path within a container. I've boiled my problem down to a simple test case.

```
docker run -it --volume=/Users/me/directory:/directory debian:jessie bash
```

I would expect to see the directory `/directory` within the container. Instead I see the directory `/Users/me/directory:/directory`.

How do I find the source of this problem and fix it?

EDIT: Formatting.

EDIT: I've found some more incriminating evidence. Certain paths mount correctly, others do not.

Works:

```
docker run -it --volume=/media/psf/Home/mounts/:/a debian:jessie bash
root@fca3f29340fe:/# ls
a  bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

Doesn't work:

```
docker run -it --volume=/media/psf/Home/mounts/a:/a debian:jessie bash
root@5d841d1ac9c6:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@5d841d1ac9c6:/# ls /media/psf/Home/mounts
a:
root@5d841d1ac9c6:/# ls /media/psf/Home/mounts/a\:
a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like that:

```
root@:~# docker run -it -v /root/a/:/tmp/a debian:jessie bash
root@e73a28616b51:/# ls /tmp/
a
```

I've added "/" at the end of the host path and it worked.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple! Thank you!

Comment: oh my god, so much time wasted because of that stupid thing